# Crystal report, 2 commands , different where clause

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, command

First question i post here so forgive me for the mistakes i am making :p

i am using crystal report 2011.
I am trying to make a report with 2 "different" commands being, the first should show all calls in total (note: cdr.aantal column) the second command should show only those that have a ringtime of 20 or less. I only use the cdr.aantal colmn of the last command and put it as the last column on my report. but for some reason it just shows the total number of calls again(not 20 or less ).
i also tried to make 1 bigger sql query(command) but that also didnt work.

first command

```
DECLARE @FromDate Date 
DECLARE @ToDate Date
set @FromDate = ('01-07-2015') 
set @ToDate = ('01-08-2015')

select [CDR].[Account], [CDR].[DnNo], COUNT ([CDR].[ID])[aantal], SUM([CDR].[Duration] [Duration], [CDR].[CdrDate], [Departments].[Description]

from [PhonEXONE].[MIND].[CDR]
Inner join [PhonEXONE].[MIND].[AllAssignmentsView]
on [CDR].[DeviceID] = [AllAssignmentsView].[DeviceID]
inner join [PhonEXONE].[MIND].[Departments]
on [AllAssignmentsView].[DepartmentID] = [Departments].[ID]

WHERE [CDR].[CdrDate] >= @FromDate AND [CDR].[CdrDate] <= @ToDate

group by  [CDR].[DnNo] ,[CDR].[Account], [CDR].[CdrDate], [Departments].[Description]
order by [CDR].[DnNo]
```

second command

```
DECLARE @FromDate Date 
DECLARE @ToDate Date
set @FromDate = ('01-07-2015') 
set @ToDate = ('01-08-2015')

select [CDR].[Account], [CDR].[DnNo], COUNT ([CDR].[ID])[aantal], SUM([CDR].[Duration] [Duration], [CDR].[CdrDate], [Departments].[Description]

from [PhonEXONE].[MIND].[CDR]
Inner join [PhonEXONE].[MIND].[AllAssignmentsView]
on [CDR].[DeviceID] = [AllAssignmentsView].[DeviceID]
inner join [PhonEXONE].[MIND].[Departments]
on [AllAssignmentsView].[DepartmentID] = [Departments].[ID]

WHERE [CDR].[CdrDate] >= @FromDate AND [CDR].[CdrDate] <= @ToDate
AND [CDR].[RingTime] >= '20'
group by  [CDR].[DnNo] ,[CDR].[Account], [CDR].[CdrDate], [Departments].[Description]
order by [CDR].[DnNo]
```

This is my 1 bigger sql

```
DECLARE @FromDate Date 
DECLARE @ToDate Date
set @FromDate = ('01-07-2015') 
set @ToDate = ('01-08-2015')

select  A.[Account], A.[DnNo], A.[aantal], A.[TDuration], A.[CdrDate], A.[Description],B.[aantal20]

from   (
select [CDR].[Account], [CDR].[DnNo], COUNT([CDR].[ID])[aantal], SUM([CDR].[Duration])    [TDuration], [CDR].[CdrDate], [Departments].[Description]
From [PhonEXONE].[MIND].[CDR]
Inner join [PhonEXONE].[MIND].[AllAssignmentsView]
on [CDR].[DeviceID] = [AllAssignmentsView].[DeviceID]
inner join [PhonEXONE].[MIND].[Departments]
on [AllAssignmentsView].[DepartmentID] = [Departments].[ID]

WHERE [CDR].[CdrDate] >= @FromDate AND [CDR].[CdrDate] <= @ToDate 
group by  [CDR].[DnNo] ,[CDR].[Account], [CDR].[CdrDate], [Departments].[Description]
) A left join 
(select [CDR].[Account], COUNT ([CDR].[ID])[aantal20]

from [PhonEXONE].[MIND].[CDR]

WHERE  [CDR].[RingTime] <= '20'
group by  [CDR].[DnNo] ,[CDR].[Account], [CDR].[CdrDate]
)B
on A.Account = B.Account
order by A.DnNo
```

again my apologies for my english and if i did something wrong
ps : i cant post images :(

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, my second command was linked to my first command  and that wasn't supposed to be the case , i deleted the link and it worked